# Sqoop is creating too many tiny files when importing data from database

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have created an automated process that incrementally imports data from database to hdfs using sqoop. Now, instead of making files as big as the block size hadoop is creating multiple tiny files. How do I instruct sqoop to make files as big as the block size?

Comment: can you provide the details of your process?> number of mappers, databases, key for incremental update, etc ?

Comment: @lake I am using 100 mappers. The database is Sybase. I am basically incrementally importing data to HDFS and then loading it onto a external table. It retrieves around 40 columns and around a million rows. The problem is it is creating a lot of small files in the target directory of sqoop query. Can you tell me what factors decide how many files will be created for an import?

Answer (score 0):

The number of files should be at most equal to your number of mappers .. Based on the size of your data, I would suggest perform the incremental updates using 1 mapper, however even doing this,  creating 1 file, you could be getting files smaller to the blocksize. You can solve this creating a different process to merge small files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of records inserted in database, sqoop incremental job create files on the HDFS, -m 1 can be passed in the sqoop command to get a single output file on hdfs.

when ever lesser records are inserted in the database, if sqoop got those records and writes in multiple files then sqoop merge job can help.